# Does "sans Adaptateur" mean that no adapter is provided?

Tags: sens

L'entreprise pour laquelle je travaille vend des produits sur Amazon Fr. Nous avons un produit avec lequel n'est pas fourni d'adaptateur, donc le prix est plus bas. Nous avons bien stipulé « **Sans Adaptateur** » dans le titre et la description du produit.

Je voudrais savoir pourquoi les acheteurs font toujours des commentaires négatifs motivés par le fait que l'adaptateur n'est pas fourni. 
Cette description est-elle inexacte?

Comment: Les commentaires sont peut-être négatifs parce que l'adaptateur est considéré comme indispensable au produit. Sinon, il pourrait être indiqué: *ATTENTION: Ne contient pas d'adaptateur.* ou *ATTENTION: Vendu sans adaptateur.*

Answer (score 23):

Bonjour,

"Sans adaptateur" peut aussi être interprété comme "Ce produit n'a pas besoin d'adaptateur", ce qui peut amener à la confusion.

Je vous conseille d'utiliser les formulations du commentaire de jlliagre
 :

> ATTENTION: Ne contient pas d'adaptateur.
>
> ATTENTION: Vendu sans adaptateur

ou celle-ci :

> Adaptateur non fourni

Comment: "ATTENTION Adaptateur non fourni" me semble en effet la meilleure formulation.

Comment: Par contre, je suggérerais « pas inclus » pour éviter qu'on peut mal interpréter (p.e. que l'adaptateur n'est pas nécessaire). [also, foreigners like myself generally seem to learn or at least recognise words like "inclus" more easily than "fourni" :)]

Comment: Effectivement, le problème c'est qu'il ne suffit pas de dire qu'il n'y a pas d'adaptateur, mais qu'il faut préciser que pour l'utiliser (en France), il en faut un. Peut-être que préciser le type de [prise] (je suppose, prise US, prise UK ou prise EU par exemple) permettrait d'éclaircir ce point

Answer (score 1):

Dans ce genre de cas il faut toujours écrire ses descriptions de produits avec l'utilisateur le plus idiot en tête (sans condescendance aucune de ma part), et bien tout préciser même si c'est évident. Dans votre cas, vous devriez préciser en lettres majuscules et entre parenthèses "ADAPTATEUR OBLIGATOIRE, VENDU SÉPARÉMENT" juste après le nom du produit.

Gardez toutefois à l'esprit qu'il y aura toujours une faible proportions de gens, de mon expérience, qui ne lisent rien de rien et mettent quand même un avis négatif même si vous avez pris toutes les précautions. Le monde de la vente est ainsi fait...

Comment: Dans le cas d'un outil ou de matériel quelconque on ne dira « obligatoire » que s'il s'agit d'une nécessité dictée par une législation. Pour une simple nécessité matérielle le terme courant est « nécessaire ».

Comment: Ils y a même ceux qui lisent très soigneusement, comprennent parfaitement et se délectent finalement en un avis négatif; telle est la clientèle…